# Delete many items from array of documents in mongodb that match this value

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to delete all documents from an array of documents that match this value but cannot figure it out,

This is my delete query that is not working, courses is the array I need to be in and code is the document I need to check to see its value for deletetion. So if courses.code == 123, then delete and keep going sort of thing.

```
 result = await mongoClient.db(DB_NAME).collection("technologies").deleteMany({ 'courses': {$in: 'courses.code'} });
```

That is what it looks like in my collection.

```
"name": "Sass",
        "description": "Sass (Syntactically awesome style sheets) is a preprocessor scripting language that is interpreted or compiled into Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).",
        "difficulty":2,
        "courses":[
            {"code":"PROG2700","name":"Client Side Programming"},
            {"code":"PROG3017","name":"Full Stack Programming"}
        ]
    },
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Yeah I want to delete the whole document so name and code that are equal to for example inside courses if code == PROG2700 delete it, and do this for every other code that meets this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can filter documents that contain the field you want to update
- Do tests **before** updates on the original collection.

After some searches, I've found this method:

```
const filter = { }
db.collection.update(filter,
{
  $pull: {
    "courses": {
      code: {
        $in: [
          "PROG3017",
          "PROG2700"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

This pulls out any element in the array where the value of code is `$in` the array.